# NodeJS Async Loop - Doesn't reach final error block

Tags: node.js, callback, ftp, async.js

I have a piece of code like this:

```
var async = require('async');
var ftp = require('jsftp');

async.waterfall([
    function(callback){
        console.log("Step 1");
        // fetch data from DB
        callback(null);
    },
    function(callback){
        console.log("Step 2");
        // FTP to remote location using a third party library
        ftp.put(fileName, remoteLocation, function(err) {
        if (!err){
          callback(null, "File transferred successfully!")
        }else {
          callback(err, null)
        }
    });
}],
function(err, result){
    if(err){
        console.log("Step 2.5")
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        console.log("Step 3");
    }
    callback(err, result);
});
```

Well, what I expect is if there's any error in the FTP of file (let's say the FTP server is down) the loop should come to "**Step 2.5**".

Instead it just throws an error (ECONNRESET if the server is down), and it never comes to the the last block where it sends a callback.

Is there any way to force async loop to complete logically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is being emitted deep in the `net.js` module of `Node` - had to look at the implementation of `jsftp`. You'll need to provide an `event listener` on the `error event` of the `FTP` object, and handle it there.

Here's a modified version of your code:

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
        console.log("Step 1");
        // fetch data from DB
        callback(null);
    },
    function(callback) {
        console.log("Step 2");
        // FTP to remote location using a third party library

        ftp.on('error', function(error) {
            callback(error);
        });

        ftp.put(__dirname + '/data/myFile', '', function(err) {
            if (!err){
              callback(null, "File transferred successfully!")
            }else {
              callback(err, null)
            }
        });
}],
function(err, result){
    if(err){
        console.log("Step 2.5")
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        console.log("Step 3");
    }
});
```

Comment: Anytime! Glad to help!